# Rails filter two associated models

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have model `Passage` that `has_many` translations and `has_one` transliteration. I'd like to filter the association given a resource id.

```
class Passage < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :translations,     class_name: 'Content::Translation',     foreign_key: 'passage_key'
  has_one  :transliteration,   class_name: 'Content::Transliteration', foreign_key: 'passage_key'
end


class Content::Translation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :resource, class_name: 'Content::Resource'
  belongs_to :passage,     class_name: 'Passage', foreign_key: 'passage_key'
end

class Content::Transliteration < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :resource, class_name: 'Content::Resource'
  belongs_to :passage,     class_name: 'Passage', foreign_key: 'passage_key'
end
```

Given that I have an array of resource ids that I'd like to filter `Content::Translation` and `Content::Transliteration` association on passage, how would I do that?

Comment: `contents` table and its model class as a parent for translation and transliteration should have type field, so it will be automatically converted to a proper class

Comment: Can you show an example of the results you want?